# Am I 'root' user on my shared hosting database?

Tags: database

I have a shared hosting in which I can create databases, and users. Is any of the users created by me `root` user?

Comment: it's shared hosting (not dedicated server, not virtual server, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a shared hosting environment you're usually not root user, nor is any of the users you can create root. This works the same among the databases you create and the users for those databases. None of those users is root.

If you're root user, you can do anything, and thus access, update and delete other users' databases, and that is not desirable for the other users.

It would work the other way around as well. The other users would likely have the same rights, so can access or delete your data and you don't want that.

I suppose your host offers a frontend like DirectAdmin or Plesk. In those cases, your admin login acts like a kind of personal-root. That personal-root can do anything to all databases you create within your account. But it cannot create a root user.

So in a normal shared hosting environment, you can only access your own databases and you are not root.